# Using HTTP standard library

Tags: ruby

Ruby http library can be used to build http user agent.
I can use it to post my form data.

But, when we are saying "form data", we first need
a physical form for user to fill up, then 
we can worry about sending the data.

Now, we are not using http library to render the physical form 
element right? how are we going to get user input? from stdin?

What do people usually use http library for?

Comment: I think you mix things up. There is no form needed for the HTTP library. It's your code's job to supply the data to be posted - either by "reading" a form or hardcoding the data in... Personally I don't use the HTTP library, but it's main use (from my experience using similar solutions) would be inter-app communications over the internet (usually involving JSON/XML and/or RESTful routing).

Answer (score 1):

The core Ruby HTTP library is provided as a "better than nothing" implementation of an HTTP client. It's not really expected to be used for anything serious outside of circumstances where you're running Ruby code in an environment where you're not permitted to install any additional dependencies, or it would be impolite to impose. It is a lot more difficult to use than other equivalent libraries.

If you're doing any serious work with HTTP in Ruby you'd use something a lot less low level. Good candidates are [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) but there are dozens of others that may be better suited depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to the standard http library, which is only suitable for standard requests without much automation, one coukd use more advanced libraries, such as 
[Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) to actually automate user interaction and fill in a html form. If you don't want to use such a library, you might as well just encode the form parameters and send a request (e.g. a POST) to the forms URL. This can be done with the standard library, e.g. with: `Net::HTTP.post_form`